# Dimension score for metric spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Given any metric space $(X,d)$, define its score $S(X)$ to be the smallest value of $k$ such that for every $x\in X$ and $r>0$, the ball $B(x,r)$ is covered by at most $2^k$ balls of radius $r/2$.

What is the growth of $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$? I guess it's $\Theta(n)$?

($S(\mathbb{R})=1$, and I'm not sure about $S(\mathbb{R}^2)$.)

Comment: $k$ is the smallest number with at most $2^k$ balls , could you elaborate the terminology ?

Comment: @SouvikDey I made a typo, which may have confused you. Just edited, is it clearer?

Comment: This was asked and answered on MO: [Doubling dimension of a Euclidean space](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100777/doubling-dimension-of-a-euclidean-space). (I think the term "doubling dimension" is in wider usage than "score").